# Merge two MySQL queries working fine separately

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
SELECT sum(monthly_target) as month_target
FROM `tbl_goal`
inner join user
    on tbl_goal.uid=user.id where user.store=1 and month='February'
```

result: **month_target = 9000**

```
SELECT
    sum(net) as achieved,
    sum(hairs_total) as hairs_total,
    sum(beard_total) as beard_total,
    sum(product_total) as product_total
FROM `data`
inner join user
    on data.uid=user.id where user.store=1 and month='February'
```

result: **achieved =103 hairs_total =63 beard_total = 40 product_total = 0**

please give me any hint how can join these into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky one.  Your current join condition implies that you want to aggregate by user, but the `WHERE` clause makes it clear that you want store-level aggregates.  So, we can try rewriting your query to aggregate by store.  Each of the two subqueries below performs separate aggregations, bringing in the `store` id via a join to the user table.  Then, on the outside we join the `user` table to each of these subqueries.

```
SELECT
    u.store,
    COALESCE(t1.achieved, 0) AS achieved,
    COALESCE(t1.hairs_total, 0) AS hairs_total,
    COALESCE(t1.beard_total, 0) AS beard_total,
    COALESCE(t1.product_total, 0) AS product_total,
    COALESCE(t2.month_target 0) AS month_target
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        usr.store,
        SUM(d.net) AS achieved,
        SUM(d.hairs_total) AS hairs_total,
        SUM(d.beard_total) AS beard_total,
        SUM(d.product_total) AS product_total
    FROM data d
    INNER JOIN user usr
        ON d.uid = usr.id
    WHERE d.month = 'February'
    GROUP BY usr.store
) t1
    ON u.store = t1.store
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        usr.store,
        SUM(t.monthly_target) AS month_target
    FROM tbl_goal t
    INNER JOIN user usr
        ON t.uid = usr.id
    WHERE t.month = 'February'
    GROUP BY usr.store
) t2
    ON u.store = t2.store;
WHERE
    u.store = 1;
```

If you wanted a report of all stores, just remove the outer `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can you check it again as its giving me error : #1305 - FUNCTION COALESECE does not exist

Comment: @VishalHira Sorry, that was a typo for `COALESCE`.  You provided us with no data, hence we couldn't test our query.

Comment: its worked like a charm :) thanks 

error gone with COALESCE(MAX(t2.monthly_target)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  sum(monthly_target) as month_target,
  sum(net) as achieved,
  sum(hairs_total) as hairs_total,
  sum(beard_total) as beard_total,
  sum(product_total) as product_total
FROM
  user
  inner join `tbl_goal` on tbl_goal.uid = user.id
  inner join `data` on data.uid = user.id
where
  user.store = 1
  and month = 'February'
```

Comment: This probably won't work, because it will result in double counting.

Comment: Even though user table is having relation with both tables?

Comment: Above query giving me error:
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "inner join" at position 321)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "inner join" at position 321)

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple inner join to achieve this . 
Try this

```
 SELECT sum(tbl_goal.monthly_target) as month_target,  sum(data.net) as achieved,
        sum(data.hairs_total) as hairs_total,
        sum(data.beard_total) as beard_total,
        sum(data.product_total) as product_total
    FROM `tbl_goal`
    inner join user
        on tbl_goal.uid=user.id
    inner join data on tbl_goal.uid=data.uid
     where user.store=1 and data.month='February'
```

Comment: This would probably result in double counting.

Comment: its giving results but not the same I wanted:

month_target =11500
achieved = 412
hairs_total = 252
beard_total = 160
product_total =0

Comment: Is this, the actual result you are expecting or the result you have got from   above query ?

Comment: Result I got from above query. My expecting result is in question. Thanks